# How to search through jQuery Array - JQuery Array Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution to SEARCH through a jQuery array or object. By this I don't mean checking if the value is contained in the array, I mean searching for related terms as user input. Just the same way we filter ArrayList in Java or even SQL LIKE clause.

For example, let's assume the following is my array

`var arr = [ 'Benson', 'Cate', 'John']`

If the user types the character `e`, then `Benson` and `Cate` should appear.

Any simplest method to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` like:

```js
var arr = [ 'Benson', 'Cate', 'John' ]
console.log(arr.filter(x => x.includes('e')));
```

Reference:

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=en)

Comment: Worked very fine. I only have a very tiny problem. The filter is case sensitive, any way to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Yes. `arr.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().includes('e'.toLowerCase()))`

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to @SimoneRossaini's answer.

```js
var arr = [ 'Benson', 'Cate', 'John' ];
const results = document.getElementById('results');
let li;
function search(s) {
    let result = arr.filter(e => e.includes(s));
    results.innerHTML = '';
    result.forEach(name => {
        li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
        results.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="search(this.value)">
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

Doesn't include JQuery though, maybe it is easy enough to translate this code to JQuery.